# How yarn knows how to run tasks that consume cores on node manager nodes with the most available cores?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-structured-streaming

we have 10 node manager nodes that co-hosted with data nodes

the available Vcore on nodes described as the following

```
                    Vcore used  Vcore Avilble
 node manager 1     56           6
 node manager 2     35           1
 node manager 3     22           40
 node manager 4     34           2
 node manager 5     36           0
 node manager 6     34           0
 node manager 7     34           2
 node manager 8     36           2
 node manager 9     35           1
 node manager 10    33           18
```

And total Vcore used and Vcore total are as the following

```
Vcore total       Vcore Used

510               440
```

lets say we run spark structured streaming application with 5 executers when each executer consume 5 core

according to Table 1 , application should run properly when its run on  `node manager 3`  machine  in that case since application consume **5 X 5 = 35** core , then on `node manager 3` we should be with available 15 Cores

but the Question is - dose yarn know which machine have the enough available cores to run the application ?

or maybe yarn run the executers on random different machines without to know which is the machine  with the available cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YARN](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) has a master component called as **Resource Manager**, whenever we submit spark application to YARN cluster, resource  manager works with services such as  **Node Manager**, **Application Master** and **Scheduler** to manage resource required for application.

Resource manager will be aware of resource availability on  each node however allocation of resources is based on other factors like current resource state on each node, number of application running, application configurations and YARN configurations.

Resource Manager will not randomly select nodes for job execution, it will try to assign tasks to  nodes which has enough resources. In your case since node 3 has enough resources which is close to 35 cores, node 3 will mostly likely to be choose.

Comment: we set in yarn configuration 2 config group for number of core , the first group is 48 core  and the second group is 96 group and node manager 3 and 10 are with 96 cores , so seems that yarn not know that node-manager 3.10 are with 96 core , what you think about ?